# EOFError while send email in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp

I am developing `Rails 3 application` where email sending failed due to error `EOFError` in `Production`.

My email setting below:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => "gmail.com",
    :user_name            => "mygmail@gmail.com",
    :password             => "passwor",
    :authentication       => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :tls                  => true
  }
```

I tried lot but not getting any solutions.

Any one ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your development.rb should look like :

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
      port:                 '587',
      domain:               'gmail.com',
      user_name:            'xxx@gmail.com',
      password:             'xxxxxx',
      authentication:       'login',
      enable_starttls_auto: true  
    }
```

There should be login in place of plain in authentication.

I hope this solves your error.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm tmp/cache/*
```

Run above command from your rails project directory and try to send mail

Comment: Nothing in cache folder. any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Heroku and it was definitely linked to credentials - I was reading in environment variables and they had not been set. Once I created them on Heroku, everything worked perfectly.